# gitignore file for Cordova 6.3.0

Tags: git, cordova, gitignore

I was working on creating a GitIgnore file for a Cordova application I am creating, for Browser, Android, and IOS.  Everything I am working on is in the www/ so i am trying to figure out what is a good `gitignore` to use.

```js
#Cordova Info
platforms/
plugins/
.idea/
www/.idea/

# ANDROID / ECLIPSE

# built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# generated files - android project subfolder
Android/bin/
Android/gen/
Android/assets/

# generated files
bin/
gen/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# IOS / Xcode
build/*
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
*.xcworkspace
!default.xcworkspace
xcuserdata
profile
*.moved-aside
IOS/www/

# OSX
.DS_Store

# Thumbnails
._*

# Files that might appear on external disk
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
```

I didnt know if this was overkill, as this is the combination of a PhoneGap GitIgnore I found + 3 folders I thought to be good to ignore, **platform, plugins, .idea**

I have been looking around and havent found anything solid.

Comment: https://www.gitignore.io/

Comment: @kcp While i like that, that doesnt really think to give me the information i need.  It really will generate one based on a series of keywords, but it doesnt have an option for the Cordova framework.

Comment: Shameless plug for my Cordova gitignore:
https://gist.github.com/elliot-labs/c92b3e52053906816074170ada511962